# Add a condition to the privilege to immediately apply your edits

Tags: discussion, edits, privileges

Right now, users who reach 2000 reputation earn the privilege to see their edits applied immediately: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

As there are many ways to earn reputation, we can imagine a scenario where a user reaches 2000 reputation only with famous questions. Yes, it is a lot of upvotes but that's possible.

In that case, he would be able to edit any post and his modifications will be applied directly without any verifications. But what if this user never edited a post before? He may be already a good editor but he can also be a terrible one.

Wouldn't it be better to add something to earn that privilege? Like the `Strunk & White` badge for example.

Little reminder:

> **Strunk & White**
>
> silver; awarded once
>      Perform a total of 80 edits between questions, answers, and tag wikis

Comment: There have not been too many cases of 2k editors being terrible (and even fewer cases of terrible editors with only a few posts), so I don't think this is necessary. Also, we have notifications to the author when their post is edited, rollback options, and edit bans / suspensions (if it's really bad) for a reason.

Comment: The edit bumps the question, and people see it afresh. If something has gone wrong, someone should/may notice, and be able to correct and otherswise address.

Comment: Haven't find it! Thks

Comment: Don't know why you emphasis only asking (good) questions so much. You can get 2000 rep without posting questions at all and without editing: by only answering other peoples questions.

Comment: Yes I know, I just posted one possible scenario

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this as a problem?  I personally don't think this is an issue.  The owner of the post is always notified of edits and they can roll them back if they don't think it was correct.  The community that visits it can also edit it if they feel the edit was bad/incorrect.

Comment: Right but the user can no longer be active. Also, an edit could decrease the quality of a post without making it too bad or changing the sense of it.

Comment: Lets say they limit the ability to do a non queued edit until you get the Strunk & White badge.  Are you going to really block someone with 100K rep just because they don't like to edit from fixing something they really want to fix?

Comment: I see your point but in that particular case, if the user doesn't like to edit, would he care to have the privilege? Plus, he can still edit, it will just go to peer review.